# Unfortunately,Camera has stopped error in android 6.01

Tags: android, android-intent

Android 6.01 gives "Unfortunately,Camera has stopped" error if we rotate our phone while video capture.this is happen only in Android 6.01 update.all other Android visions lock camera after capturing start.But android 6.01 camera rotate if we rotate our phone.This is not happen in default camera.This is happen only if we use Intent to capture video.

activity_video_app_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".VideoAppMainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Record"
    android:id="@+id/recordButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/recordButton" />
```

VideoAppMainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoAppMainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mRecordView, mPlayView;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private int ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_app_main);

        mRecordView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        mPlayView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        mRecordView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callVideoAppIntent = new Intent();
                callVideoAppIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(callVideoAppIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
            }
        });

        mPlayView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_video_app_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu_video_app_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".VideoAppMainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nigelhenshaw.com.videoapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoAppMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">VideoApp</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: try to go to the permission of your app 
might be u didn't have permission to access it

Comment: "Android 6.01 gives "Unfortunately,Camera has stopped" error if we rotate our phone while video capture" -- unless your app is named "Camera", you are seeing a bug in whatever camera app is handing your request. There is little that you can do about this.

Comment: This is not a permission issue

Comment: Can you add crash log? What exception is thrown by system?

Comment: this is happen in every android camera app in android 6.01 when capturing a video.i want to lock camera rotation.android can stop screen rotation but we can't stop camera rotation.

Answer (score -1):

From  6.0 Marshmallow you have to take permission
There are two types of permission in android 
check this link

[Go here and read and try to get permission dynamically when user open camera 1st time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Or You can try this code

```
 private void requestPermission()
    {
        checkPermission();

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Storage permission allows us to send Image. Please allow in App Settings for Complete your order.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }
```

Add this on your click

```
// click of Button ImageCamera
case R.id.ImageCamera:
                if(!checkPermission())
                requestPermission();
                break;
```

Also add this in Manifest

```
<!--external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This is not a permission issue this is happen when we rotate while capturing.